# How to use DefaultHttpClient in Android?

Tags: android, httpwebrequest, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

How to use DefaultHttpClient in Android?

Comment: you could have put a little more energy to the question....

Comment: It seems like this question could stand to be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suggest reading the tutorials provided with android-api.

Here is some random example which uses DefaultHttpClient, found by simple text-search in examples-folder.

EDIT: The sample-source was not intended to show something. It just requested the content of the url and stored it as string. Here is an example which shows what it loaded (as long as it is string-data, like an html-, css- or javascript-file):

**main.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/textview"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  />
```

**in onCreate of your app add:**

```
  // Create client and set our specific user-agent string
  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://stackoverflow.com/opensearch.xml");
  request.setHeader("User-Agent", "set your desired User-Agent");

  try {
      HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

      // Check if server response is valid
      StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
      if (status.getStatusCode() != 200) {
          throw new IOException("Invalid response from server: " + status.toString());
      }

      // Pull content stream from response
      HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
      InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();

      ByteArrayOutputStream content = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

      // Read response into a buffered stream
      int readBytes = 0;
      byte[] sBuffer = new byte[512];
      while ((readBytes = inputStream.read(sBuffer)) != -1) {
          content.write(sBuffer, 0, readBytes);
      }

      // Return result from buffered stream
      String dataAsString = new String(content.toByteArray());

      TextView tv;
      tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
      tv.setText(dataAsString);

  } catch (IOException e) {
     Log.d("error", e.getLocalizedMessage());
  }
```

This example now loads the content of the given url (the OpenSearchDescription for stackoverflow in the example) and writes the received data in an TextView.

Comment: When i implementing this code the output show me nothing. Plz sir kindly gives me the complete code to access data from url using httpclient

Comment: I changed the example so that it shows the received data in an TextView.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a general code example:

```
DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpGet method = new HttpGet(new URI("http://foo.com"));
HttpResponse response = defaultHttpClient.execute(method);
InputStream data = response.getEntity().getContent();
//Now we use the input stream remember to close it ....
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Google Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html)

`public DefaultHttpClient (ClientConnectionManager conman, HttpParams params)`

Creates a new HTTP client from parameters and a connection manager.

Parameters
`"conman"`  the connection manager,
`"params"`  the parameters

```
public DefaultHttpClient (HttpParams params)
public DefaultHttpClient ()
```