# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: android, json

I am creating android application, in which there is a search module where user enters the data then it send to server and server sends the output back to the user and it is displayed in form of table.

My problem is that i am getting this error

```
  06-02 00:08:43.971  19902-20586/com.diamond.traders W/SingleClientConnManager﹕ Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
    Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
06-02 00:08:43.991  19902-20586/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Not Found
06-02 00:08:43.991  19902-20586/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:71)
06-02 00:08:43.991  19902-20586/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:59)
06-02 00:08:43.991  19902-20586/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
06-02 00:08:43.991  19902-20586/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
06-02 00:08:43.991  19902-20586/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
06-02 00:08:43.991  19902-20586/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at com.diamond.traders.Search_result$GetDatafromDB_Searchresult.getDataFromDB(Search_result.java:676)
06-02 00:08:43.991  19902-20586/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at com.diamond.traders.Search_result$1.run(Search_result.java:80)
06-02 00:08:43.991  19902-20586/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
06-02 00:08:43.991  19902-20586/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ Exception : Not Found
06-02 00:08:43.991  19902-19902/com.diamond.traders E/log_tag﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

here is my networking code and here is the [link to complete code](http://pastebin.com/vmBjhq5j). Sorry can't add here as it is very long.

```
public class GetDatafromDB_Searchresult {

        public String getDataFromDB() {


            try {

                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.106/test/search1.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
                //add your data
                nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar,
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("carat1", strcolor1.toString().trim()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("carat2", strcolor2.toString().trim()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("color1", strclarity1.toString().trim()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("color2", strclarity2.toString().trim()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cut1", strcut1.toString().trim()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cut2", strcut2.toString().trim()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("shape1", strshape1.toString().trim()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("shape2", strshape2.toString().trim()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stones", strstone.toString().trim()));


                // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                //Execute HTTP Post Request
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                final String response1 = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
                System.out.println("Response : " + response1);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
            }

            return response1.trim();

        }
    }
```

here is my server side code

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost ="localhost";
$database_localhost ="testdb";
$username_localhost ="root";
$password_localhost ="";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

 mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

$carat1 = $_POST['carat1'];
$carat2 = $_POST['carat2'];
$color1 = $_POST['color1'];
$color2 = $_POST['color2'];
$cut1 = $_POST['cut1'];
$cut2 = $_POST['cut2'];
$shape1 = $_POST['shape1'];
$shape2 = $_POST['shape2'];
$stones = $_POST['stones'];



$query_search ="Select * from search1 where 
carats = $carat1 and carats = $carat2 and 
color = '$color1' or color =  '$color2' and 
 cut = '$cut1' or cut = '$cut2' and 
 shape = '$shape1' or shape = '$shape2' and 
 stone ='$stones'";

$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());


    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_exec))
            $json_output[]=$row;
      echo json_encode($json_output);

    mysql_close();

?>
```

EDIT:
This is the output from the server.

```
06-02 00:02:08.229  19428-19481/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ [{"id":"1","product_code":"sdfsd","shaps":"fsdfsd","pair":"fsdf","carats":"sdgfdhn","color":"gnfgng","clarity":"jmf","service":"fgnfgnf","polish":"gnfg","symetric":"nfgnfg","tables":"nfgjkrtyr","measurments":"tjrt","flourscne":"jrtjr","description":"tjrtjgmgv","certificated":"mvbmv","ccode":"bmvb","cut":"kmty","total":"yttynyt","file":"tyfjfjgjfg"},{"id":"2","product_code":"fgn","shaps":"fgmkyh","pair":"wqqfwfw","carats":"fsfsdsdf","color":"gsdfwe","clarity":"fsdfsdf","service":"sdfs","polish":"dfsd","symetric":"fsdfs","tables":"dfsdf","measurments":"sdf","flourscne":"sdfsd","description":"fsdfsdd","certificated":"sfs","ccode":"dfsd","cut":"fsdf","total":"sdf","file":"sdf"},{"id":"3","product_code":"xfcbxcb","shaps":"xcbx","pair":"cbxcb","carats":"xcb","color":"xcbx","clarity":"cxcbxc","service":"xcb","polish":"xcbx","symetric":"cbxc","tables":"bxcb","measurments":"xcbxc","flourscne":"b","description":"xcbxcb","certificated":"xcbx","ccode":"cbx","cut":"cbxc","total":"bxc","file":"b"},{"id":"4","product_code":"xcb","shaps":"xcb","pair":"xcbxc","carats":"bxc","color":"bxc","clarity":"bxc","service":"bxc","polish":"xc","symetric":"bxcb","tables":"xcbx","measurments":"cbx","flourscne":"cbx","description":"cbxcbxcb","certificated":"xcbxc","ccode":"bxc","cut":"bxcb","total":"xcb","file":"xc"}]
```

Comment: post all the logcat ( e.printStackTrace(); )

Comment: I did put everything that is there in the logcat, there are not other error, rest is just the output of each inputs. I did print them just to check if all the inputs are correct or not.

Comment: you did catch the erroe and print as e.getMessage(); it should be e.printStackTrace();

Comment: i did modify the question and have added the output from e.printStacktrace();

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not getting return response correctly.  Try something like this...

```
HttpResponse response = defaultHttpClient.execute(httppost);
InputStream data = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

Comment: where shall i use InputStream? Can you please elaborate and explain to me.

Comment: @SamvidKulkarni Check this post for a simple example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410823/how-to-use-defaulthttpclient-in-android

Comment: The tutorial about displaying content data from the site. In my case it displays content in form of JSON. is tutorial still valid for me? I have added the output from the server in the question.

Comment: For a general tutorial there are lot online to choose from - http://bit.ly/1m3Cxps

Comment: @SamvidKulkarni Here is another example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374156/sending-and-parsing-response-using-http-client-for-a-json-list

Comment: @SamvidKulkarni I created a library for this today, feel free to use it, or copy how I did the post requests - https://github.com/nathansizemore/java-json-http-client